# Bigquery: dbt seed with ARRAY fields

Tags: dbt

I'd like to load some small configuration table I have on BigQuery using seeds.
I did that successfully till now, but now I have a table with an array field.
I put the arrays in the usual BigQuery format ["blablabla"], but no luck.
I tried forcing the datatype in dbt_prject.yml, but I get a "ARRAY is not a valid value" error.
Did someone ever used seeding with structured fields?
Daniele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, unfortunately. From a little online research, this appears to be a joint limitation of:

- the BigQuery [LoadJobConfig](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.schema) API that dbt calls [here](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/blob/dev/kiyoshi-kuromiya/plugins/bigquery/dbt/adapters/bigquery/impl.py#L722-L724)
- the CSV file format, which doesn't really have a way to specify a nested schema ([related issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3673))

A long-term resolution to this may be support for JSON-formatted seeds ([dbt#2365](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/2365)).

In the meantime, I recommend that you set the seed column type to `string` and convert it to an array (using [`json_extract_array`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array)) in a staging model.